# Compact,connected set

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity, compactness, connectedness

How could be proved that a function that sends compacts into compacts and connected into connected implies f continuous ? 
I’d appreciate even just the idea behind that (if the proof is too long) 
Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is true.

Comment: Could sin(1/x) be a counter-example?

Comment: @ChrisCulter I don't think this duplicates that question. This question is not restricted to $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I'm assuming that the OP is working with some unstated assumptions, since they seem to be looking for a proof of a true statement.

Comment: @ChrisCulter possibly. On the other hand, there are lots of requests on this site for proofs of false statements.

Comment: I don’t know if it’s true or false,i’d like to know it (and why) so that i could work on the proof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and $f : X \to Y$.

If $X$ is a totally disconnected space its only connected subsets are singletons. In this case $f$ sends connected sets to connected sets.

If $Y$ is a two-point set then every subset of $Y$ is compact. In this case $f$ sends compact sets to compact sets.

So, you should look for a discontinuous function from (say) the irrational real numbers with the relative topology to the set $\{0,1\}$ to obtain a counterexample.